# After apt-get autoremove my desktop style has changed

Tags: unity, apt

After doing `apt-get autoremove` my unity desktop is messed up. I have menus in the application title bar even though it is not set that way. My system font changed as well and program guis are styled differently. How can I get it back to normal?

I've tried reinstalling ubuntu-destktop and unity but the problem remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by removing the package `appmenu-qt`